# Google App Engine Maven plugin 1.7.4 -appengine-maven-plugin - configuration (appId) and artifactId

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using appengine-maven-plugin (of sdk version 1.7.4). I have created a sample maven project based on the guestbook archetype.

My artifactid is 'myApplication' but my GAE appId is something else e.g  myGAEApplication.

I am trying to use the

mvn appengine:update goal, and I have altered my pom.xml with something like

---

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <configuration>

                <appId>myGAEApplication</appId>
```

---

But it does not seem to work. Any ideas on having different artifactId and differentGAE app id. it is supposed to work but am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with the sample guest book application by changing the app id in the application-web.xml file to the application Id in my appengine account.

Comment: yes it works if you directly edit the application-web.xml but I would assume that the plugin and the 'update' goal woul eventually read the specific property in its configuration and generate the appropriate .xml in the /target. It seems that the related property is only used during the appconfig upload that the plugin does ..and not to generate the right dist files.